# Field not showing up in coveo range facet dropdown

Tags: content-search, coveo

I've defined a new facet Price in `/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Facets` but it does not show up in the Field dropdown when I try to add a `Coveo Range Facet View`.

I can only see 2 fields in the dropdown as opposed to 10+ fields that are defined in `/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Facets` folder.

I've already rebuilt the coveo indexes multiple times.
The Price field does show up in regular `Coveo Facet View`'s dropdown. 
Is there anything else I need to do?

Update: seeing this warning in logs, WARN  The item with ID 'Price' could not be found. The item ID will be returned instead of the list value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen a similar behaviour and the reason was that the the type of the field I had set on my /buckets/facets was not compatible with the type of the facet I was using.
What's the type your field is getting indexed as?

Comment: The field is of type string but I am converting it to a float by creating computed field.

Comment: are you using this computed field on your /bucket/facet item? Also is this computed field a facet?

Comment: I created my item under /bucket/facet and used its File Name (lowercase one) to create computed field that convert's its value to float instead of string.

Comment: the computed field is a facet too.
under AddComputedIndexField: <field fieldName="price">Site.FloatParserComputedField,Site</field> and under fieldMap/fieldNames: <fieldType fieldName="price" isSortable="true" isFacet="true" settingType="Coveo.Framework.Configuration.FieldConfiguration, Coveo.Framework" />

Comment: I ended up modifying the field type on the template of Coveo Module. After that it seems to work fine.